# Como remover do título <title> do painel a palavra "WordPress"?

Tags: wordpress

Como posso fazer para remover o nome "WordPress" dos títulos dentro do painel administrativo?

Ex: Quando entra no Painel (Dashboard), todas as páginas no título fica o nome **WordPress**, como eu poderia remover essa palavra?

Fica mais ou menos assim: `Painel < Meu Site -- WordPress`

Queria somente: `Painel < Meu Site`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aqui a forma correta de fazer isso usando o filtro `admin_title`:

```php
function custom_admin_title( $admin_title ) {
    return str_replace( ' &#8212; WordPress', '', $admin_title );
}

add_filter( 'admin_title', 'custom_admin_title' );
```

Comment: onde se inclui o add_filter?

Comment: @PapaCharlie [Where do I put the code snippets I found here or somewhere else on the web?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/72160/12615)

Comment: @PapaCharlie Na grandessíssima maioria dos temas, fica no **functions.php**. Temas mais elaborados (na maioria comerciais) tem mecanismos próprios para injetar esses recursos (mas ainda assim através da "API" do WordPress).

Comment: Ou usa no functions.php do tema, ou faz um plugin. Que neste caso seria apenas criar um arquivo `.php` com o cabeçalho assim http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin#File_Headers e então colocar na pasta de plugins do WordPress.

Comment: Excelente! Ficou 100% Vlw

Comment: Criei um plugin mesmo, é muito melhor!

Answer (score 0):

Não uso o WordPress, mas tenho aqui. Não sei se se faz no pacote de tradução, mas encontrei no arquivo `wp-admin/admin-header`.
Linhas 31 - 34

```
if ( $admin_title == $title )
    $admin_title = sprintf( __( '%1$s &#8212; WordPress' ), $title );
else
    $admin_title = sprintf( __( '%1$s &lsaquo; %2$s &#8212; WordPress' ), $title, $admin_title );
```

Comment: Sim, isso mesmo! Vlw, só que queria colocar seu código como plugin, pois se eu colocar diretamente, quando eu atualizar o wordpress, o arquivo vai ser substituido, e minha alteração não terá mas efeito.

Comment: Papa, como posso fazer isso? e @brasofilo você que manja em plugins, sabe como fazer isso?

Comment: Eu não tenho ideia de como se faz plugin. Sempre que se atualiza os arquivos são substituídos?

Comment: Sim :( infelizmente...

Comment: Teria que ser um plugin para rodar apos cada atualização, mas  não há garantias. O WP pode mudar a variavel de `admin_title` para `WPadmin_title`... Também não pode ser substituindo a linha fixada... Veja o custo x beneficio

Comment: Acho que tem que usar `remove_function` e `add_function` não sou bom com plugins também. Vou esperar pelo @brasofilo pois ele manja nos paranauê.

Comment: Nunca edite nada do core do WordPress, ainda mais porque tem filtros e actions para fazer praticamente qualquer personalização. Veja a minha resposta ensinando a usar o filtro `admin_title`. Bem simples de resolver o problema de uma forma que vai sobreviver a qualquer atualização do WordPress.

Comment: Fazer um plugin é muito simples, é só [colocar um cabeçalho](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin#File_Headers) e colocar seu código (tipo o da resposta do Claudio). @AlexandreLopes, o `@usuario` só funciona pro pessoal envolvido num post (autor da pergunta/resposta, editores e comentadores), fora isso não há aviso pro `@usuarioAlheioAoAssunto` ;)

Comment: Vlw Bras! você é 10... rsrs